# How to force android to use Bluetooth for telephony? (if bluetooth is connected)

Tags: bluetooth, audio, calls, automotive-head-unit

I have some problems with Android telephony in my car.

I connect my android phone over bluetooth with the car (the radio has a build-in telephone function).
Since the car does not support bluetooth audio, I connect the phone to the 3.5mm jack of the car.
The audio works pretty good, music, navigation, etc. is sent over the 3.5mm jack.

Now when I want to call someone (or get called) I have some annoying bugs.

With my old smartphone (Sony Xperia X Compact, Android 8, using the 3.5mm jack of the phone) I had a 50% chance, that when I start a call, the phone chooses the 3.5mm jack as an output, so while dialing I had to switch to bluetooth in the dialer app.
Now, with my new smartphone (OnePlus 8 Pro, Android 10, using a USB-C to 3.5mm jack adapter) the bug got way more annoying. When the call starts and is dialing it always uses bluetooth but as soon as the call partner takes the call it switches to the 3.5mm jack and I have to switch back to bluetooth manually (resulting in me not hearing others until I switch).

Now my question is: Is there any way to force android to use bluetooth for calls when bluetooth and 3.5mm jack are connected?

I found some pretty old questions here (the other way round) where apps have been suggested that don't exist anymore.

I also already tried the following with tasker (without any luck):

- I created a new task that sets Bluetooth voice transmission to on
- I created a new profile that executes this task when I'm connected with my car's bluetooth
- I created a new profile that executes this task whem I'm connected with my car's bluetooth and a call has been accepted

Sadly this didn't work.